# How to change Okular's "Find..." highlight color?

Tags: kde, pdf, okular

When I am using the "Find..." feature in Okular, the matches are highlighted in yellow. How can I change this color?

I also add annotations to PDF files in Okular and the default color for text highlighting is also yellow (and now I have many annotations that are yellow). Therefore, sometimes I cannot see the matches if I have already highlighted them.

Answer (score 7):

Cannot add as comment in question because of low reputation, but here's [the ongoing bug discussion](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=384267). One workaround (not ideal, I know, and it doesn't work for already highlighted texts) would be to change the default highlighter color...

To do so (Okular v1.1.3), go to Settings -> Configure Okular -> Annotations -> Select highlighter in the "Annotation tools" list -> Edit -> And change default color.

Comment: Then you should add the information for that workaround here. Your answer like this will be likely a candidate for deletion otherwise.